# Adding Selected JList component to Object

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I just made a small program where customers chooses 3 colours from the JList
and some how I need to add these colours to Customers object

I have Constructor like this

```
    public Customer (String cc1, String cc2, String cc3){
    this.colour1 = cc1;
    this.colour2 = cc2;
    this.colour3 = cc3;
```

And simple code i wrote is this

```
public class Test2 extends JApplet {
Container container;
JButton b1;
JPanel panel;
JTextArea area;
String[] colours = {"Yellow", "Orange", "Red", "Purple",
        "Blue", "Green", "Brown", "Black", "White"};
JList list, selectList;
String cc1, cc2, cc3; //Chosen colour

public void init() {
    container = getContentPane();
    panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    area = new JTextArea();
    b1 = new JButton("Submit");
    list = new JList(colours);
    selectList = new JList();
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(5);

    panel.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    panel.add(b1);
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(selectList));
    panel.add(area);
    container.add(panel);

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
                Object selected[] = list.getSelectedValues();
                selectList.setListData(selected);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

How do I make it so that colour that person has chosen goes to Customer object
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Customer` already exists, then you need some kind of setter, otherwise just create a new `Customer` object

You want to take the selected values from the list and add them to a `String` array which you can control, but you only want to add up to a maximum of 3 items

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object[] values = list.getSelectedValues();
        String[] colors = new String[3];
        for (int index = 0; index < Math.min(3, values.length); index++) {
            colors[index] = values[index].toString();
        }
        Customer customer = new Customer(colors[0], colors[1], colors[2]);
    }
});
```

Or something simular

Comment: I was planning on creating new Customer Object every for loop.

Comment: What loop?  For each selected item?  Does each `Customer` get the same colors?

Comment: So every Customer will have colors0 ~ 2

Comment: How many customers?  Do they all get the same list of selected colors?

Comment: I'm planning adding extra attribute to the Customer "name" and Array of Customer object that can have up to 100 customers and they will all have different selected colors